# Moduli space of trigonal curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have two questions about trigonal curves, hopefully I didn't make stupid mistakes :

> Let $f_1 : X_1 \to \mathbb P^1, f_2 : X_1 \to \mathbb P^1$ be two trigonal curves. Is it true that $X_1 \cong X_2$ if and only if there is $A \in PGL_2(\mathbb C)$ such that $f_1 = Af_2$ ?

If yes, it implies that $T_g$ (the moduli space of trigonal curve of genus $g$) has dimension $2g+1$. This implies that $\dim M_g = \dim T_g$ for $g=4$.

> Is it true that a generic curve of genus $4$ is trigonal ?

I know that a generic curve of genus $4$ can be realised as a complete intersection of a quadric and a cubic in $\Bbb P^3$. I also tried to use Riemann-Roch with a divisor of degree $3$ but with no success.

Comment: Did you mean if $\sigma$ is an isomorphism $X_1\to X_2$ then $f_1= A f_2 \sigma$ for some $A\in PGL_2$ ?

Comment: Project the genus $4$ curve to either factor of the quadric surface $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$, doesn't it give you a degree $3$ map to $\mathbb P^1$?

Comment: @reuns : I was implicitly identifying $X_1$ and $X_2$ but indeed this is what I meant.

Comment: @AGlearner : Thanks this seems to work ! Do you have any idea about the first question ?

Comment: @nicolas You may want to look at the paper Moduli of Trigonal Curves by Stankova-Frankel. I haven't really looked at your questions, but they may very well be answered in here.

Comment: @nicolas Isn't a generic curve of genus $3$ trigonal? Note that the moduli space $T_3$ is open in $M_3$ (the moduli space of smooth genus $3$ curves). But the latter has dimension $3g-3 = 6$ when $g=3$, whereas $2g+1 = 7$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar : Indeed, a curve of degree $3$ that is not hyperelliptic is a curve of degree $4$ in $\Bbb P^2$, hence trigonal. Maybe I made a mistake in my computation.

Comment: @TabesBridges : thanks for the reference, I will look it up.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Here was my reasoning : there is a finite map $\{ f : X \to \Bbb P^1 : \deg(f) = 3 \}$ to its branch points (because its fully determined by the monodromy). Now, the biggest possible number of branch points is when each ramification point has multiplicity $2$, by Riemann-Hurwitz this gives $2g - 2 = -6 + b$ hence $b = 2g + 4$. Now, there is an $SL_2$ action on $b$, giving a count of $2g+4 - 3 = 2g -1$. Of course, if the answer to 1) is "no", then the dimension might be even smaller. But I'm not sure how to check that.

Comment: @nicolas How many trigonal maps does a (fixed) non-hyperelliptic genus 3 curve admit? Is it maybe a "one-dimensional" family? That might explain the discrepancy. Here's what you might try: The moduli space of degree $3$ maps $X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ with $X$ non-hyperelliptic maps surjectively to the moduli space of quartic curves by only remembering $X$. The latter has dimension $6$ whereas the former has dimension $7$. Maybe that's because the fibres of this morphism are one-dimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just recording comments that solves the question :

1. It can't be true, as explained in comments by Ariyan Javanpeykar. More precisely, a curve of degree $4$ in $\Bbb P^2$ is trigonal (blowing up a point in $\Bbb P^1$ gives a morphism $X \to \Bbb P^1$ of degree $3$). It implies that $T_3$ is dense in $M_3$, but the dimensions don't match.
2. As AG learner said, a (smooth) quadric in $\Bbb P^3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^1 \times \Bbb P^1$, hence a generic curve of degree $4$ is trigonal.

Note : for hyperelliptic curve, the map $X \to \Bbb P^1$ is actually unique (up to $PGL_2$-action)since it is the canonical map.

Comment: For genus at least 5, statement 1 is true, see https://amathew.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/hyperelliptic-and-trigonal-curves/